# Dict in List comprehension Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, list-comprehension

I have a List with API results:

```
result = [(True, 
        {'result': 
            {'skus': 
                [{'sku': '123'}, {'sku': '124'}]
                }
        }
    ),
    (True, 
        {'result': 
            {'skus': 
                [{'sku': '125'}, {'sku': '126'}]
                }
        }
    )
]
```

So, I need to get each `'sku'`

I can do it in two loops:

```
for elem in result:
for sku in elem[1]["result"]["skus"]:
     print(sku)
```

How can I do it in one string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do it in one string?

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
print([sku for elem in result for sku in elem[1]["result"]["skus"]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to extract all the `'sku'` values from the result list in a single line of code.

```
    result = [(True,            {'result':              {'skus':                [{'sku': '123'}, {'sku': '124'}]
             }
           }
          ),
          (True, 
           {'result': 
             {'skus': 
               [{'sku': '125'}, {'sku': '126'}]
             }
           }
          )
         ]

skus = [sku['sku'] for elem in result for sku in elem[1]['result']['skus']]

print(skus)
```

This will print a list of all the `'sku'` values:

```
['123', '124', '125', '126']
```

The list comprehension is essentially a shorthand way of writing the nested for-loops in a single line. The output of the list comprehension is a list of all the `'sku'` values extracted from the `'result'` list.

Answer (score 1):

Linear time complexity with one for-loop:

```
[result[x][1]['result']['skus'] for x,y in enumerate(result)]

#[[{'sku': '123'}, {'sku': '124'}], [{'sku': '125'}, {'sku': '126'}]]
```

Edit as suggested by @buran

```
[item[1]['result']['skus'] for item in result]
```

Comment: Please, don't advise code like `range(len(result))`

Comment: Thanks @buran I edited. I also don't like range. enumerate is the way to go:)

Comment: There is no need to use index at all `[item[1]['result']['skus'] for item in result]`